# How to split only on carriage returns with readlines in python?

Tags: python, newline, carriage-return

I have a text file that contains both `\n` and `\r\n` end-of-line markers. I want to split only on `\r\n`, but can't figure out a way to do this with python's readlines method. Is there a simple workaround for this?

Answer (score 10):

As @eskaev mentions, you'll usually want to avoid reading the complete file into memory if not necessary.

[`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) allows you to specify a `newline` keyword argument, so you can still iterate over lines and have them split *only* at the specified newlines:

```
import io

for line in io.open('in.txt', newline='\r\n'):
    print repr(line)
```

Output:

```
u'this\nis\nsome\r\n'
u'text\nwith\nnewlines.'
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `io.open` is Python 3's builtin `open` function. You only need to look for it in the `io` module in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid reading it in text mode. Python reads texts files with [universal newline support](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/). This means that *all* line endings are interpreted as `\n`:

```
>>> with open('out', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(b'a\nb\r\nc\r\nd\ne\r\nf')
... 
14
>>> with open('out', 'r') as f: f.readlines()
... 
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd\n', 'e\n', 'f']
```

Note that using `U` doesn't change the result<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> with open('out', 'rU') as f: f.readlines()
... 
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd\n', 'e\n', 'f']
```

However you can always read the file in binary mode, decode it, and then split on `\r\n`:

```
>>> with open('out', 'rb') as f: f.read().split(b'\r\n')
... 
[b'a\nb', b'c', b'd\ne', b'f']
```

(example in python3. You can `decode` the bytes into unicode either before or after the `split`).

you can avoid reading the whole file into memory and read it in blocks instead. However it becomes a bit mroe complex to correctly handle the lines (you have to manually check where the last line started and concatenate it to the following block).

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe it's because universal newline is enabled by default in all normal installations. You have to explicitly disable it when configuring the installation and *then* the `r` and `rU` mode would have different behaviours (the first would only split lines on the OS native line endings, the latter would produce the result shown above).

Answer (score 1):

This approach reads the file as a generator in chunks split by your separator.

```
ifs = open(myFile)
for chunk in ifs.read().split(mySep):
    #do something with the chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using readline, just use read and the split.

For Example

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    fileContents = f.read() #read entire file
    filePieces = fileContents.split('\r\n')
```