# readlines in R on \r\n not \n

Tags: r

I have a number of webchat logs like this:

```
 Agent: Click here. \n Then click here. \n Then do this. \r\n

 Customer: Show me. \r\n

 Agent: Ok. \n One Second. \r\n
```

When I import them into R I only want to treat \r\n as the new line, not \n. I don't see an option to do that in readline()? Is there a best way to do this?

Here is a solution on Stack Overflow in Python: [How to split only on carriage returns with readlines in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457144/how-to-split-only-on-carriage-returns-with-readlines-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into whether one could use `readLines()` to do this, but I didn't see an easy way to do it with `readLines()`.

It seems that the base function `readline()` is not useful here.

A work-around is to read the text in with scan, then parse the result.

For instance, if your text is in foo.txt:

```
words <- scan("foo.txt", what = "character")
words2 <- words[words != "\\n"]
onepar <- paste(words2, collapse = " ")
library(stringr)
lines <- str_split(onepar, pattern = fixed(" \\r\\n"), simplify = TRUE)
lines

    [,1]                                                [,2]                       [,3]                      [,4]
[1,] "Agent: Click here. Then click here. Then do this." " Customer: Show me." " Agent: Ok. One Second." ""
```

You could then remove the whitespace to get something similar to what I think that you want.

I wish that I had a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think it gets a little simpler if you use `readr::read_file` instead of `scan`.